# MySQL import file with no column delimiter

Tags: mysql-5.5, import

Is there a way to use the `mysqlimport` command on a file that has no column delimiters?

I would like to import the `ctl` file used with the `sqlloader` for Oracle

Comment: Is it fixed width?

Comment: See this similar question: [Convert fixed length text file into SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564166/convert-fixed-length-text-file-into-sql/6564868#6564868)

Comment: yes you're right, I tried that and it works, I think this question could be closed as exact duplicate of the one you suggested, how do I close this ?